# how to count voluntary context switches on older kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, proc

I want to find the number of voluntary context switches for a given pid.

I can find this using /proc/pid/status but non voluntary and voluntary context switches info was added from kernel 2.6.23.

I have to get this info on an older kernel. How can I do that ?
My kernel version is -- 2.6.18

man page for proc entry that mentions the kernel version for this info -- 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember this old kernel has not supported TRACE EVENTS yet.
So, may be you should hack your kernel ))). E.g. add counter in struct task_struct and will be increment when context is switched.